# Return value undefined when calling class in Node js, Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am kinda new to node js and express framework. I am trying to pass value to a javascript class to process a query and make a call to database, and i expecting a result array. here is my code:

here is my Router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Database = require('../app/database.js');

var mysqlConnect = new Database()

router.get('/data-penjualan', (req, res) => {
    var start_date = req.query.start_date;
    var end_date = req.query.end_date;
    var city = req.query.city;
    // console.log(start_date);
    var result = mysqlConnect.generalData(start_date, end_date, city);
    console.log(result);
    res.render('header')
});

module.exports = router;
```

and here is my database.js app:

```
"use strict";
var mysql      = require('mysql');

module.exports = class Database {
  connect(query) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : '###',
      user     : '###',
      password : '###',
      database : '###'
    });
    connection.connect();
    return connection.query(query, function(error, results, fields){
      if (error) {
        console.log('connection to database error');
      } else {
        var result = results;
        connection.end(function(err){
          if (err) {
            console.log('fail to end the connection');
          } else {
            console.log('connection has end after all query executed');
          }
        });
      }
      console.log(result);
      return result
    });
  }
  generalData(start_date, end_date, city) {
    if (city == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      var query = `SELECT o.date_add, o.current_state , o.id_order, CONCAT(c.firstname , ' ' , c.lastname) AS fullname,
      REPLACE(TRIM(LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s.name,',',2),",",-1))), 'kota administrasi ', '') AS city,
      a.phone_mobile, c.email, od.product_name, od.total_price_tax_excl FROM ps_orders AS o
      LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail AS od ON o.id_order = od.id_order
      LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer
      LEFT JOIN ps_address AS a ON o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address
      LEFT JOIN ps_state AS s ON a.id_state = s.id_state
      WHERE o.date_add BETWEEN '${start_date}' AND '${end_date}'
      AND o.current_state IN (2,4,5)
      HAVING city REGEXP '${city}' ;`;
    }
    // console.log(query);
    this.connect(query);
  }
}
```

on console.log(result); on database.js i able to log the result, but on console.log(result); on my router the value return UNDEFINED. How can i fix this ? thanks

Comment: In your `generalData` function, you execute the query but never return the result, so the function will always evaluate to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read a bit about JS (and NodeJS) event driven nature.

In your code:

```
connect(query) { // (1)
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '###',
    user     : '###',
    password : '###',
    database : '###'
  });
  connection.connect();
  return connection.query(query, function(error, results, fields){ // (2)
    if (error) {
      console.log('connection to database error');
    } else {
      var result = results;
      connection.end(function(err){
        if (err) {
          console.log('fail to end the connection');
        } else {
          console.log('connection has end after all query executed');
        }
      });
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result // (3) !!! This return is not for (1), it is for (2)
  });
}
```

`return` statement (3) makes the return value of the callback (`function(error, results, fields){`) passed to the `connection.query()` to be `result`. But due to asynchronous nature of JS function `connect(query)` has already returned it's return value and it was something that `connection.query()` returned when it was called - `connection.query()` returns immediately, it does not wait for callback to complete.

If you would like to continue to use callback, then your code should look like this:

```
"use strict";
var mysql      = require('mysql');

module.exports = class Database {
  connect(query, callback) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : '###',
      user     : '###',
      password : '###',
      database : '###'
    });
    connection.connect();
    return connection.query(query, function(error, results, fields){
      if (error) {
        console.log('connection to database error');
        return callback(error); // report error, return to stop processing
      } else {
        var result = results;
        connection.end(function(err){
          if (err) {
            console.log('fail to end the connection');
          } else {
            console.log('connection has end after all query executed');
          }
        });
      }
      console.log(result);
      // return result no need for this
      return callback(null, result);
    });
  }
  generalData(start_date, end_date, city, callback) {
    if (city == null) {
      return callback(null, null); // functions should be consistent in a way they return data: either sync return or async callback
    } else {
      var query = `SELECT o.date_add, o.current_state , o.id_order, CONCAT(c.firstname , ' ' , c.lastname) AS fullname,
      REPLACE(TRIM(LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s.name,',',2),",",-1))), 'kota administrasi ', '') AS city,
      a.phone_mobile, c.email, od.product_name, od.total_price_tax_excl FROM ps_orders AS o
      LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail AS od ON o.id_order = od.id_order
      LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer
      LEFT JOIN ps_address AS a ON o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address
      LEFT JOIN ps_state AS s ON a.id_state = s.id_state
      WHERE o.date_add BETWEEN '${start_date}' AND '${end_date}'
      AND o.current_state IN (2,4,5)
      HAVING city REGEXP '${city}' ;`;
    }
    // console.log(query);
    this.connect(query, callback); // simply pass provided callback, your this.connect() will call it with something
  }
}
```

Otherwise you could use async/await with Promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. since i am new to this, let's say i am following your solution, how to pass the value to the router ?

Comment: `mysqlConnect.generalData(start_date, end_date, city, (error, result) => {
  console.log(result);
  res.render('header');
});`

Comment: As it is stated in the docs (http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html, Response methods): *The methods on the response object (res) in the following table can send a response to the client, and terminate the request-response cycle. If none of these methods are called from a route handler, the client request will be left hanging.*

Comment: It means that you can call any `res` methods in callbacks.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, now it's already solved. Thanks for your time